# Splitting a series in two with zeros and the series value

Tags: matlab

I have the following in table in matlab

```
k   ak
0   1
1   -0.166666667
2   0.008333333
... ...
```

where ak = (-1)^k/(2k+1)! but that's not really important, all that is important is that ak is a function of k and the (-1)^k.

I am trying to generate a new set of columns as below

```
i   ai
0   1
1   0
2   -0.166666667
3   0
4   0.008333333
... ...
```

So far I've figured out that by stretching my indices (incrementing by 2 instead of 1) and applying the ak function it gets pretty close to what I want but it returns the absolute value.

```
if mod(i,2)=0
  ai=(-1)^i/factorial(2*(i/2)+1);
else
    ai=0;
end
```

How can I change this to be what I want?

Comment: You want zeros interleaved?  `ai(1:2:end) = ak` will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using this:

```
ai = (-1)^(ii/2)/factorial(2*(ii/2)+1);
% Notice ----^
```

Your `if`-`else` statements can be given a vector input and written in one-line as:

```
ai = ~mod(ii,2) .* (-1).^(ii/2)./factorial(2*(ii/2)+1);
%I used ii instead of i since i is for imaginary numbers in MATLAB
```

Comment: Won't this result in complex numbers?

Comment: @WnGatRC456 no it won't.  `~mod(ii,2)` takes care of that